# Fetch data from Oracle Database on hourly and daily basis using timestamp and current date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp, format

I have written query to get data for a particular day, but need a query to get the data on hourly and daily basis

My Query:

```
SELECT 
TRAN_USERTRANSACTIONS.APPLICATIONNUMBER 
FROM 
TRAN_USERTRANSACTION 
WHERE TRAN_USERTRANSACTIONS.CREATEDAT 
LIKE '%19-09-19%' 
GROUP BY 
TRAN_USERGTRANSACTION.APPLICATIONNUMBER;
```

CREATEDAT is Timestampin in format as follows :DD-MM-YY hh.mm.ss.ssss AM/PM

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data, actual output and expected output.

Comment: Hi, Could you provide more info on what you actually want? Do you mean you want to know how to run this query on an hourly/daily basis, or are you asking for a single query to return data separated into hours of the day?

Comment: i want two queries one for hourly basis and one for daily basis @BarryPiccinni

Answer (score 0):

By hour(hope this helps):

```
Select TRAN_USERTRANSACTIONS.APPLICATIONNUMBER
       , TO_CHAR(TRAN_USERTRANSACTIONS.CREATEDAT ,'HH AM')
from TRAN_USERTRANSACTION
WHERE TRAN_USERTRANSACTIONS.CREATEDAT LIKE '%19-09-19%' 
group by TRAN_USERTRANSACTIONS.APPLICATIONNUMBER 
         , TO_CHAR(TRAN_USERTRANSACTIONS.CREATEDAT ,'HH AM')
order by TO_CHAR(dat_azu,'HH AM') asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a summary by hour and not by application.  If so, the hour should be in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(t.CREATEDAT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') as dh,
       COUNT(*) 
FROM TRAN_USERTRANSACTION t
WHERE t.CREATEDAT >= DATE '2019-09-19' AND
      t.CREATEDAT < DATE '2019-09-20'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(t.CREATEDAT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24')
ORDER BY dh;
```